# How to ignore double quotations while importing using phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

I have a file that looks like this

```
"1106837", "Jabbar", "33.29106", "73.48639", "PK", "Asia/Karachi"
"1106838", "Dhangdev Saiyidān", "33.26424", "73.41412", "PK", "Asia/Karachi"
"1106839", "Dheriān", "33.255", "73.42722", "PK", "Asia/Karachi"
.
.
.
```

When import the file using phpmyadmin following statement is executed.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE  'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\phpC108.tmp' INTO TABLE  `allcountries` FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY  ',' ENCLOSED BY  '"' ESCAPED BY  '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\r\n'(
`geonameid` ,  `place_name` ,  `lat` ,  `lng` ,  `country_code` ,  `city`
```

The problem is that the double quotations( *"* ) are also inserted into the table columns. I don't need the double quotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your fields are not terminated by `,`, they're terminated by `,`  (with the extra space in the termination string). Try the following:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE  'C:\\wamp\\tmp\\phpC108.tmp' INTO TABLE  `allcountries` FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY  ', ' ENCLOSED BY  '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\r\n'(
`geonameid` ,  `place_name` ,  `lat` ,  `lng` ,  `country_code` ,  `city`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespaces from the text file, mysql client cannot parse them.

```
"1106837", "Jabbar", "33.29106", "73.48639", "PK", "Asia/Karachi"
```

=>

```
"1106837","Jabbar","33.29106","73.48639","PK","Asia/Karachi"
```